# Use props to pass another component(+props) to be rendered and keep type safety

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to pass a Component to a wrapper component including props to be rendered inside the wrapper component. Typescript should validate that the passed props belong to the passed component as well as doing type checking.

This is the prop to pass to the component:

```
act?:componentAct<T>
```

This works partially:

```
interface componentAct<T>  {
  component: React.ComponentType<T>,
  props:T
} 

interface WrapperProps<T> {
  act?: componentAct<T>
}

interface ActorProps {
  name: string
}

const Wrapper: React.SFC<WrapperProps<ActorProps>> = props => {
  const componentAct = props.act
  const Comp = componentAct!.component
  return <Comp {...componentAct!.props}>{props.children}</Comp>
}


const Actor = (props: ActorProps) => {
  return <div {...props}>test123</div>
}

const appNode = document.getElementById('app')

ReactDOM.render((<Wrapper act={{component: Actor, props:{name:'test'}}} />), appNode);
```

However

> React.SFC < WrapperProps< ?>>

I don't want to pass ActorProps (instead of the question mark) here because the wrapper props doesn't know which props Actor is using because Wrapper is in another library that Actor.

Another issue here is that a component might not have props (and then props should be omitted from componentAct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 2.9 or later you can use a generic component which will allow you to pass in the generic parameter. We can also use a conditional type to make the `props` field required only when the component has props:

```
interface componentAct<T> {
    component: React.ComponentType<T>,
    props: T
}

interface WrapperProps<T> {
    act?: keyof T extends never ? { component: React.ComponentType<T>, props?: never } : componentAct<T>
}

interface ActorProps {
    name: string
}

const Wrapper = function <T>(props: WrapperProps<T> & { children?: React.ReactNode }) {
    const componentAct = props.act
    const Comp = componentAct!.component
    return <Comp {...componentAct!.props}>{props.children}</Comp>
}

const Actor = (props: ActorProps) => {
    return <div {...props}>test123</div>
}

let ok = (<Wrapper<ActorProps> act={{ component: Actor, props: { name: 'test' } }} />)
let errorNoProp = (<Wrapper<ActorProps> act={{ component: Actor }} />) // Property 'props' is missing in type '{ component: (props: ActorProps) => Element; }'.
let errorExtraProp = (<Wrapper<ActorProps> act={{ component: Actor, props: { name: 'test', s: "" } }} />) // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 's' does not exist in type 'ActorProps'.
let errorForgottenGenericParam = (<Wrapper act={{ component: Actor, props: { name: 'test' } }} />)

const NoParams = () => {
    return <div>test123</div>
}

let okNoPropsRequired = (<Wrapper act={{ component: NoParams }} />)
let errorPropsExtra = (<Wrapper act={{ component: NoParams, props: { bla: "" } }} />)
```

Comment: This works! 
Only thing is that  <Wrapper<NotActorProps> act={{ component: Actor, props: { notBelongToActProp: 'test' } }} still compiles. No check that the jsx generic belongs to Actor

Comment: @PeterBartels what is the definition of `NotActorProps` ? I actually get an error on `interface NotActorProps { notBelongToActProp: string}
let nok = (<Wrapper<NotActorProps> act={{ component: Actor, props: { notBelongToActProp: 'test' } }} />)`

Comment: My bad, it was my IDE. Works like a charm now!